# R: For loops with different criteria filling 2 vectors with the same data

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

Writing R code to fill 2 vectors with the data received amounts on a wi-fi system on a train.

(Empty vectors to eventually be filled with data from received data vector)

```
movingnorth <- vector('numeric')
movingsouth <- vector('numeric')
```

(Vectors containing 2800 values each)
    latitude <- ts01$lat
    received <- ts01$tprx

(If the train is moving north, fill the moving north vector with data from received vector)

```
for(y in 1:length(latitude)){
  if (y < length(latitude)){
  if(latitude[y]<= latitude[y+1]){
    movingnorth <- c(movingnorth, received[y])
  }
    else {
      break()
    }
  }
}
```

(If the train is moving south, fill the moving south vector with data from received vector)

```
for(z in 1:length(latitude)){
  if (z < length(latitude)){
  if(latitude[z] >= latitude[z+1]){
    movingsouth <- c(movingsouth, received[z])
  }
    else {
      break()
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that the movingnorth and movingsouth vectors are being filled with the same data. The moving north vector contains 632 values after running the code, and the moving south contains 109, but those 109 values match the first 109 values of moving north. Obviously, a train cannot be moving both north and south at the same time.

Comment: can you add example data and desired output?

Comment: Maybe for the first 109, the train stood still and therefore the condition `latitude[y] == latitude[y+1]` was fulfilled? That would work for both `latitude[y] <= latitude[y+1]` and `latitude[z] >= latitude[z+1]`. Or it moved exactly west or east, and no north/south movement was registered, therefore not changing the latitude.

Comment: Welcome to Circle 3 
http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @LAP you're exactly right, the train was still during the first 109 entires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need a loop, lets look at this toy example:

```
latitude <- c(1,2,1,3,2) # latitude coordinates
received <- 1:5

require(data.table)
d <- data.table(lat = latitude, rec = received)
d
#    lat rec
# 1:   1   1
# 2:   2   2
# 3:   1   3
# 4:   3   4
# 5:   2   5
d[, dif := c(0, diff(lat))] # if positive moved N, if negative S
movingnorth <- d[dif >= 0, rec]
movingsouth <- d[dif < 0, rec]
movingnorth
#[1] 1 2 4
movingsouth
# [1] 3 5
```

Comment: When you create the new column in the table "dif" why do you use c(0, diff(lat)) instead of just diff(lat)? @minem

Comment: @Brad because diff(lat) does not calculate difference between first and first element ( which is 0), so i add it manually, so we can get the correct length vector.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use loops for this. It can be done easily in a vectorized way:

```
#reproducible example
set.seed(42)
latitude <- sample(20, replace = TRUE)
#[1] 19 19  6 17 13 11 15  3 14 15 10 15 19  6 10 19 20  3 10 12
received <- rnorm(20)
#[1]  1.3048697  2.2866454 -1.3888607 -0.2787888 -0.1333213  0.6359504 -0.2842529 -2.6564554 -2.4404669  1.3201133
#[11] -0.3066386 -1.7813084 -0.1719174  1.2146747  1.8951935 -0.4304691 -0.2572694 -1.7631631  0.4600974 -0.639994

#find directions, be a bit fuzzy around zero, adjust for precision of latitudes if necessary
direction <- cut(diff(latitude), c(-Inf, -1e-16, 1e-16, Inf), c("south", "neither", "north")) 
#[1] neither south   north   south   south   north   south   north   north   south   north   north   south   north   north  
#[16] north   south   north   north  
#Levels: south neither north

#split the vector (after discarding last value)
split(head(received, -1), direction)
#$south
#[1]  2.2866454 -0.2787888 -0.1333213 -0.2842529  1.3201133 -0.1719174 -0.2572694
#
#$neither
#[1] 1.30487
#
#$north
#[1] -1.3888607  0.6359504 -2.6564554 -2.4404669 -0.3066386 -1.7813084  1.2146747  1.8951935 -0.4304691 -1.7631631
#[11]  0.4600974

#if neither needs to be combined with north
head(received, -1)[direction %in% c("neither", "north")]
#[1]  1.3048697 -1.3888607  0.6359504 -2.6564554 -2.4404669 -0.3066386 -1.7813084  1.2146747  1.8951935 -0.4304691
#[11] -1.7631631  0.4600974
```